# use more than 100 features lm function in R

Tags: r, lm

Assume I have a dataframe consisting of 101 columns, where the first 100 are named data1 to data100 and the 101th column is named y.

If I want to use the lm function in R where data1 to data100 are the features.

I know this can be written as:

```
lin_reg <- lm(y ~ data1+...+data100, dataframe)
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You should not do this at all. OLS regression with that many predictors will result in some serious issues. You can expect severe collinearity. Also don't be surprised by computational issues.

Answer (score 4):

```
lin_reg <- lm(y ~ ., data = dataframe)
```

This assumes your data is really only consisting of your outcome + all feature variables. No extra column. The "." indicates "take everything else from that data frame".

Since - as per comment - the TO wants to exclude certain columns:

```
data_frame_subset <- dataframe[, !names(dataframe) %in% c("data5", "data10")]
lin_reg <- lm(y ~ ., data = dataframe_subset)
```

In this example, I would exclude the columns data5 and data10.

Comment: Thanks, but what if some columns should be ignored. For example column "data5".

Comment: Than you should mention this in your question. However, see an update to my post.

Comment: Another way to exclude `data5` will be: `lm(y ~ . - data5, data = dataframe)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the formula dynamically with `reformulate` :

```
lin_reg <- lm(reformulate(paste0('data', 1:100), 'y'), dataframe)
```